# Правильно ли здесь поставлено двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли употреблено двоеточие или лучше с "Так вот" начать новое предложение?

Недавно мы были на выставке во Франкфурте, где встречались с теми, кто уже участвовал в нашем мероприятии и других выставках: так вот, страны, объявившие нам санкции, «втихаря» стараются выйти на наш рынок, считая, что кризис — это самое хорошее время для того, чтобы остаться «на плаву» и развить бизнес.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно мы были на выставке во Франкфурте, где встречались с теми, кто уже участвовал в нашем мероприятии и других выставках: так вот страны, объявившие нам санкции, «втихаря» стараются выйти на наш рынок, считая, что кризис — это самое хорошее время для того, чтобы остаться «на плаву» и развить бизнес.

Может быть, здесь не нужна запятая после "так вот", имеется в виду: таким вот образом?

Тогда можно оставить двоеточие, так как идет раскрытие темы: факт участия говорит о старании выйти на рынок. Желательно связать два сообщения, не разделяя их на предложения.Лучше бы даже тире поставить, но одно тире здесь уже есть.

Comment: Нет, мне кажется, здесь "так вот" именно частица, только мне кажется, что двоеточие в таком случае неуместно.

Comment: Запятая меняет семантику сообщения: так/так вот/вот так - это всё указательные конструкции без обособления, а "так вот" с обособлением - это словосочетание с оттенком вводности. Но смысл предложения с обособленным "так вот" не очень понятен, поэтому двоеточие кажется лишним.

Comment: Я бы перед "так вот" поставил точку или точку с запятой (в этом месте заканчивается предшествуюшее самостоятельное суждение), а двоеточие переставил.

Так вот [что выяснилось]: страны...

Если же дальнейшее должно логически следовать для читателя из факта встречи, а не из подразумеваемого содержания бесед на ней, то вместо "так вот" можно сказать "Так что вот (вам):" или "Как видите,".